# Is there a regex pattern matching nested phrases?

Tags: regex

Having the string `"The cat is (black|white)"`, I can get the result phrase `"The cat is black"`, using the pattern `/\((.*?)\|.*?\)/`, and replacing the first match in the string. So for example in PHP, using `preg_replace('/\((.*?)\|.*?\)/', '$1', $phrase)`

Now I would like to extend the pattern, in order to obtain the same result string, that is `"The cat is black"`, also from the start string `"The (cat is (black|white)|dog is (black|white))"`.

The pattern should be working for both types of phrases.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a regex is the wrong tool for the job. It would probably be _way_ simpler to just parse the string into a simple tree structure

Comment: Regular expressions are not very good at dealing with balanced patterns like this.

Comment: What do you want returned if the string is `"The (cat is (white|black)|dog is (black|white))"`? If `"The (cat is (white|black)|dog is (white|black))".`? Where you have `(X|Y)` must `X` and `Y` each be `white` or `black`? If one is `white` must the other be `black`? You can see that the wording of your question is vague; you must correct that tendency to do well in coding.

Comment: As I indicated in my comment above, I do not understand the question. Is it enough to convert matches of `\(|\|.*` to empty strings? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TAN7m6/1)

Comment: Not sure, generally an idea is to resolve it from inside like [`$regex = '~\(([^)(|]*)\|[^)(]*\)~'; do { $str = preg_replace($regex, '$1', $str, -1, $cnt); } while ($cnt > 0);` (php demo)](https://tio.run/##ZY69DoJAEIR7nmILkrslmEiNP60lhZ2gwWPDEYlc4BJNPHn1cw/t7GY3882M0cb7zb44FFEUT3aELYijJpCqttBNIK99rW7uoTtL6Jqh/XuiyBkdqaVngOdSytMZpasSLF1QVVLiHEzNAC/4lRgGLiMZDiL5pVMQcSbSxZHCKmOl7hZzeAM39bwp3LCDNXIYKT0s1tz7Dw)

Answer (score 1):

This problem isn't really suitable for a direct regular expression solution. However, it's easily solved by writing a short recursive function that expands the alternate phrases described by the pattern.

You didn't tag this question with a language, so I will provide an example implementation in Python. You should be able to translate it to your language of choice.

Given the function

```py
def pattern2alternates(pattern: str) -> Iterator[str]:
    try:
        # Attempt to find a subpattern enclosed in parentheses.
        open_pos = pattern.index("(")
        close_pos = pattern.rindex(")")
    except ValueError:
        yield pattern
        return
    
    prefix = pattern[:open_pos]
    middle = pattern[open_pos+1:close_pos]
    suffix = pattern[close_pos+1:]
    
    # Split the pattern on each '|' not enclosed by parentheses.
    for alt in re.split(r"\|(?![^\(]+\))", middle):
        # Recursively expand subpatterns for the current alternate.
        for sub in pattern2alternates(alt):
            yield f"{prefix}{sub}{suffix}"
```

you can expand your input pattern as

```py
>>> input_pattern = "The (cat is (black|white)|dog is (black|white))"
>>> print(list(pattern2alternates(input_pattern)))
['The cat is black', 'The cat is white', 'The dog is black', 'The dog is white']
```

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I solved it like this, using PHP:

```php
function unfoldPattern($string)
{
    $result = preg_replace('/\(([^(]*?)\|.*?\)/', '$1', $string);
    
    if ($result != $string)
    {
        return $this->unfoldPattern($result);
    }
    
    else
    {
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**